# How can I send information from a php program to fortran?

Tags: php, fortran, ipc, send

I have a fortran program that I want to call from php with some arguments passed from php via a website.

I have the php form set up, but I don't know how to send the information to fortran. Currently , the information is input to the fortran program through prompts:

```
write(\*,'("give input image name:",$)')
read(\*,\*) iminput
```

So I want to send an array, or something similar so I can have

```
CHARACTER(LEN=*) :: iminput 

iminput = post(1)
```

Or something similar.

Comment: We're going into the past Marty.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a program that expects its parameters on standard input instead of as command line arguments, you can still automate passing the information by using a pipe. For example, if the program asks for your name and age, you could feed these in in one go from the shell, without waiting for it to ask, by doing:

```
echo -e "user1795485\n1 day" | theprogram
```

For your problem, you need to be able to run your program, write to its standard input and then read its response back from its standard output. I think [proc-open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) will let you do exactly this. Example 1 on that page is exactly what you want, I think. Basically, you would call `proc-open`, then write the information the fortran program expects, close the write handle and then read back the results. Note that the fortran program does not need to be modified in any way.

Comment: Ok, so I'm working on testing that, and here's some additional questions: If I run the fortran program by running magic.e, would I do this? 
`$process = proc_open('magic.e', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);`
with everything else being the sameish?

Also, where do I put the information to pass to magic.e? Is that `fwrite($pipes[0], 'my image.png');` ?

Thanks for the response.

Comment: What you write to $pipes[0] will be what the fortran program reads using `read(*,fmt)`. What the fortran program writes using `write(*,fmt)` is what you will be able to read from $pipes[1] after you have closed $pipes[0].